# ¿Como puedo entrar al código de un botón VB.NET? Si el html viene de sublimeText

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Buenas tardes amigos.

Hice un login en html con Bootstrap en un editor de texto y lo copie y pegue en VB.Net visual studio 2015, en los botones ya agregue el asp:Button runat="server" pero al dar doble clic en el botón no me manda al código para programar en VB. si no al html del boton. Me gustaría saber si tengo que modificar en web.config??

Answer (score 0):

hehehe nada tiene que ver el web.config lo que debes hacer es reemplazar todo ese bloque de html por controles asp, así en lugar de tener un

> < buton>Boton html< buton>

tendrás

> < asp:Button ID="btnAsp" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Botón asp" OnClick="btnAsp_Click" />

y de esa forma recién podrás obtener lo que buscas.